# Applescript. Choose from list and launch selection

Tags: applescript

I have a script that asks for a folder first, then launches the files of that folder as a list, then I select the file, and then it launches it. But I want it to open the contents of a pre-specified folder as a list and then I select from the list and then for it to launch it. I don't want to have to go through the step of having to select the folder each time.

The script I have is:

```
    set sourceFolder to choose folder
    tell application "Finder" to set filelist to name of every file of sourceFolder
    set selectedFiles to choose from list filelist with multiple selections allowed
    if selectedFiles is false then return
    repeat with aFile in selectedFiles
    tell application "Finder" to open file aFile of sourceFolder
    end repeat
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer found. For anyone having the same issue. in a crosspost on reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/applescript/comments/x51z0g/comment/imyyeqm/?context=3

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. – From [answer].

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it [is better](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.